# Should I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 16.04 (64 bit) for Core i5 M540?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, performance

I have Lenovo L412 with core i5 M540 processor (2.53 Ghz) and recently upgraded to 8 gb RAM. Also has a Intel(R) HD Graphics Card, nothing fancy. Should I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 16.04 (64 bit) for Core i5 M540 for better performance ?

Comment: Try both of them and select the version that works best in your computer. If they both are good, select the newer LTS version (18.04 in this case), because it will last longer (until end of life).

Comment: Although having said to use the newer LTS version, you might find it prudent to wait for the maintenance LTS version of 18.04 to be released (expected July/August IIRC)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has [a memory leak that's being fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297), so if you have to install Ubuntu today and can't wait, maybe 16.04 will be the way to go (and it's still supported until April 2021). You might also look into the more lightweight Xubuntu and Lubuntu to improve performance a bit. Get 18.04 with those since they don't have that memory leak. They're supported until April 2021 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18.04 uses the 4.15 kernel which has [some protection against Spectre and Meltdown](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/1/28/173) attacks, so it's worthy of consideration.

I would suggest Xubuntu or Lubuntu; since this isn't a gaming-class machine, you might not need the full features of the GNOME desktop environment, and as noted above, with these systems you avoid the memory leak issue in the current Ubuntu build.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer's specifications meet the recommended requirements of both releases.

I recommend installing Ubuntu 18.04 since it is the newest LTS release which means it will last longer (it will be supported till 2023).

Also, Ubuntu 16.04 runs on Unity as a default Desktop Environment; however, all LTS releases starting from 18.04 are running on GNOME by default. So it would be better to adapt to GNOME from now since it is the future approach of Ubuntu.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297 describes the GNOME memory leak bug you should know about.